# Error Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, babeljs

I am new to react/redux/webpack and am trying to setup a new project from scratch and I encountered **Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token**

I have tried answers to similar questions but havent been able to solve it.

Stacktrace

```
ERROR in ./Counter.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:6)

  14 |   render() {
  15 |     return (
> 16 |       <h1>Hello</h1>
     |       ^
  17 |     );
  18 |   }
  19 | }

 @ ./app.js 3:0-32
 @ multi ./app.js
```

.bablelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    './app.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: [ 'react', 'es2015' ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile": "webpack",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './Counter';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Counter),
    document.getElementById('mount')
  );
});
```

counter.js

```
import React from 'react';
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
}
export default Counter;
```

Comment: 1) Show the full *error and stacktrace* 2) Show the relevant code

Comment: Added the stacktrace and the app.js file

Comment: Why are you using both `rules` and `loaders`? Use one or the other

Comment: Thanks that solved it

Answer (score 1):

Modified my `.babelrc` code with the following and it solved it:

```
{
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "stage-2"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified my webpack.config.js with the below code and solved it.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    './app.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: [ 'react', 'es2015' ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};
```